# How to Mock the void method call which is present inside static method using Mockito and Junit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have class TestME which has static main method. I need to avoid the call of b.cool method.

```
public class TestME {
    public static int testme(String ...strings){
        System.out.println(strings.length);
        B b = new B();
        b.cool();
        return strings.length;
    }
}
```

My B class is below

```
public class B {
   public void cool(){
      System.out.println("I am cool");
   }
}
```

My Junit class for above TestMe class is below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JunitTest {

    @Spy
    B b;

    @InjectMocks
    TestME test;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        test = new TestME();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe(){
        doNothing().when(b).cool();
        Assert.assertEquals(2, test.testme("xyz", "omg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me what i am missing or is this possible with mockito or not or do i need to use powermockito or any workaround.

Comment: You can't do anything because you create an instace of `B` within method body. Try to refactor code not to call `B` constructor, e.g. by passing `B` instatnce as the parameter

Comment: what do you plan to mock? you can verify that the method has been called, but it's not like you should return "mocked" data

Comment: @JakubCh. Thanks but this is the main method from where i need to run the code. So how can i pass the instance of B in method parameter.

Comment: @Stultuske I am just trying to avoid the call of b.cool() method.

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: I am trying to create a pdf file in my application but for Junit testing i don't want to call this pdf creation method() that's why i need to avoid this call using mockito. pdf file  is consuming too much of heap space area that's why I have written this simple example.

Comment: @sbisen I posted my answer

Comment: @JakubCh.Thanks a lot for the help and details answer. I will use power mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change your code from:

```
public class TestME {
    public static int testme(String ...strings){
        System.out.println(strings.length);
        B b = new B();
        b.cool();
        return strings.length;
    }
}
```

To the following:

```
public class TestME {
    public static int testme(String ...strings){
        System.out.println(strings.length);
        B b = getInstanceOfB();
        b.cool();
        return strings.length;
    }

    static B getInstanceOfB(){
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Then in your test code you may spy on the class, stub `getInstanceOfB()` method to return mock object. Having this true `b.cool` would be never called in tests.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestME.class)
public class JunitTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
        PowerMockito.spy(TestME.class);
        PowerMockito.when(TestME.getInstanceOfB()).thenReturn(b);
    }

   @Test
    public void testMe(){
        Assert.assertEquals(2, TestME.testme("xyz", "omg"));
    }
}
```

You'll need a PowerMockito to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling static method no need to mock the TestMe. Simple call like TestMe.testme as below.

```
@Test
    public void testMe(){
        doNothing().when(b).cool();
        Assert.assertEquals(2, TestMe.testme("xyz", "omg"));
    }
```

Comment: I am getting output as "2 and I am cool ". But i need only output as 2.
I am trying to avoid a call to b.cool() method.